# Why are certain aesthetics functions of my graph not displaying?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I enhance the graph visibility of my data labels (Perhaps to make them float above the bar graph itself) and to also increase the space between my graph and the border to accommodate space for my data labels?

This is my current graph.

[image]

Furthermore, I have difficulty adding a legend with a title to my graph. I have input a code statement as part of my ggplot2 is as follows to add the legend but it is not working. How can I also add a different color to each data legend rather than a uniform color of brown as shown below.

```
 +scale_fill_discrete(name = "Type of sale", labels = c("New Sale", "Resale", "Sub Sale"))
```

This is my full code:

```
#Load Libaries

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
options(scipen = 100000)
library(scales)
library(stringr)

#Read dataset
ura <- read.csv('URAdata_new.csv') 

#Data cleaning
ura <- ura %>% mutate(Date.of.Sale_month = str_split(ura$Date.of.Sale, '-', simplify = T)[, 1],
               Date.of.Sale_year = str_split(ura$Date.of.Sale, '-', simplify = T)[, 2])


#Graph construction
ura %>% group_by(Type.of.Sale) %>% summarize(avg_price = mean(Price....)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Type.of.Sale, y = avg_price)) + geom_col(fill = 'brown') +
  labs(x = 'Type of sale', y = 'Average price', title = 'Average price across different types of sales',color='Types of Sales') +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Type of sale", labels = c("New Sale", "Resale", "Sub Sale"))+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::comma(round(avg_price, 2))), vjust= -0.15)+
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(colour="red",size=14, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue",size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour="green",size=14, face="bold"))+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Average Price",labels = comma)
```

Where did the mistake happen? What changes could I make to the code to show my legend, make my data values float above the graph, increase the space between the graph border and my graphs, as well as make my graphs display in different colors for diff legends such as resale, new sale and sub sale?

This is my dput() output

```
> dput(head(ura,20))

structure(list(Project.Name = c("V ON SHENTON", "V ON SHENTON", 
"STIRLING RESIDENCES", "PARC CLEMATIS", "STIRLING RESIDENCES", 
"ONE PEARL BANK", "TWIN VEW", "WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", 
"WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", "WHISTLER GRAND", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", "KENT RIDGE HILL RESIDENCES", 
"STIRLING RESIDENCES"), Street.Name = c("SHENTON WAY", "SHENTON WAY", 
"STIRLING ROAD", "JALAN LEMPENG", "STIRLING ROAD", "PEARL BANK", 
"WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", 
"WEST COAST VALE", "WEST COAST VALE", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", "SOUTH BUONA VISTA ROAD", 
"STIRLING ROAD"), Type = c("Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", 
"Apartment", "Apartment"), Postal.District = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L
), Market.Segment = c("CCR", "CCR", "RCR", "OCR", "RCR", "RCR", 
"OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "OCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR", 
"RCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR", "RCR"), Tenure = c("99 yrs lease commencing from 2011", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2011", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2019", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2019", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2017", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", "99 yrs lease commencing from 2018", 
"99 yrs lease commencing from 2017"), Type.of.Sale = c("Resale", 
"Resale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", "New Sale", 
"New Sale"), No..of.Units = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Price.... = c(3548000L, 
3490000L, 1987000L, 1745000L, 1227000L, 1702000L, 1899000L, 704380L, 
1129960L, 1145540L, 1473540L, 1421880L, 1367000L, 1360000L, 3000000L, 
870000L, 1711000L, 899000L, 870000L, 1249000L), Nett.Price.... = c("-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Area..Sqft. = c(1518L, 1518L, 
1055L, 1044L, 635L, 700L, 1249L, 441L, 764L, 764L, 990L, 958L, 
775L, 786L, 1776L, 484L, 958L, 484L, 484L, 635L), Type.of.Area = c("Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", 
"Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata", "Strata"), Floor.Level = c("46 to 50", 
"46 to 50", "26 to 30", "06 to 10", "31 to 35", "21 to 25", "26 to 30", 
"21 to 25", "21 to 25", "21 to 25", "31 to 35", "31 to 35", "01 to 05", 
"01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", "01 to 05", 
"16 to 20"), Unit.Price...psf. = c(2338L, 2299L, 1884L, 1671L, 
1932L, 2433L, 1521L, 1596L, 1479L, 1499L, 1488L, 1484L, 1764L, 
1731L, 1689L, 1796L, 1786L, 1856L, 1796L, 1967L), Date.of.Sale = c("20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", 
"20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun", "20-Jun")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

If the data is not extensive enough, I have input a google sheet link as well:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QFXNUpgEjjPGdfXUwvzYIadnoxcD2-Ba6cw6BqrxfO8/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To get bars of different colors put `fill` in `aes` with value as `Type.of.Sale`.
- To make the data labels float decrease the `vjust` value
- Increase the limits of y - axis to create enough space.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ura %>% 
  group_by(Type.of.Sale) %>% 
  summarize(avg_price = mean(Price....)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Type.of.Sale, y = avg_price, fill = Type.of.Sale)) + 
  geom_col() +
  labs(x = 'Type of sale', 
       y = 'Average price', 
       title = 'Average price across different types of sales') +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Type of sale", 
                      labels = c("New Sale", "Resale", "Sub Sale"))+
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::comma(round(avg_price, 2))), vjust= -1.8)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(colour="red",size=14, face="bold.italic",hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour="blue",size=14, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour="green",size=14, face="bold")) + 
    scale_y_continuous(name="Average Price",labels = scales::comma, limits = c(0, 2500000))
```

[image]